# Handling UntrustedSSLcertificates using WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I got stuck in handling UntrustedSSLcertificates using web driver in Java.

I created firefox profile like:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
```

I created  firefox profile, added  overridden certificate.

This is not handling SSL certificates.

Is there any other way to handle UntrustedSSLcertificates?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually I found solution for Untrusted SSLCertificates:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile","your custom firefox profile name");
String browserProfile = stem.getProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile");
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile(browserProfile); 
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates (true); 
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: It looks as if `stem.getProperty` on the third line should be `System.getProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

//Firefox example with URL www.google.com

```
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

driver=new FireforDriver(profile);

driver.get("https://google.com");
```