# Bypassing CERT Exception in Webdriver with Java Language binding

Tags: java, webdriver, ssl-certificate

I have an https login page from a Web App which i am trying to automate using Webdriver.

Login URL: https://a.b.c.d/web/certLogon.jsp

i looked at [handling-untrustedsslcertificates-using-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933871/handling-untrustedsslcertificates-using-webdriver)

but since my cert was NOT prepared against a.b.c.d (Which is usual in testing environments) this would not work.
and i get error :
(Error_code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

So, is it possible to pypass host check altogether ? similar to how we do it in HttpsURLConnection ?

```
URL url = new URL(httpsURL);

            HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();

            httpsCon.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

This seems to be SUCH a common use case, so one would think that Webdriver SHOULD have solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
```