# FirefoxProfile settings are being ignored

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

Using Selenium WebDriver 3.0.1.0 with Marionette and geckodriver 0.11.1 and Firefox 50 from C#. I have used `FirefoxOptions` motivated by this ObsoleteAttribute:

> FirefoxDriver should not be constructed  with a FirefoxBinary object.
>   Use FirefoxOptions instead.

The code is:

```
FirefoxOptions fo = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", DOWNLOAD_FOLDER);
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("trustAllSSLCertificates", true);
firefoxProfile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;

fo.Profile = firefoxProfile;
driver = new FirefoxDriver(fo);
```

It looks to me, like the `firefoxProfile` specified is not being used at all, SSL certificate errors appear and dowload dialog is being displayed regardless on profile settings. I thought that it does not ignore SSL certificate errors because of [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40788935/2224701), but it looks like all the profile settings are being ignored.

How to make that the profile settings take effect? (so that no download dialog appears and SSL errors are ignored)

That code worked before switching to Marionette, looks like Marionette is not yet ready to use?

Comment: I have switched back to IceDragon and Selenium 2.53 and everything is working again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that profile settings were actually ignored:

1. You should check `MIME` type of file you intend to download. Does it really `text/csv`?
2. There is no such preference as `trustAllSSLCertificates`. I think you need `firefoxProfile.SetPreference("security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling", false);`

Comment: The code worked before switching to Marionette. But I will try the 2, thanks.

Comment: The settings `"security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling", false` made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is working smoothly to avoid visiting SSL certificate errors page:

```
    public static FirefoxOptions FfOptions()

            {
                FirefoxOptions option = new FirefoxOptions();
                option.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
                return option;
            }

    public static IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(FfOptions());
```

Comment: I can verify this only after I switch back to Marionette but I guess it has improved over years.