# Geckodriver/Selenium 3.x doesn't seem to like proxies

Tags: java, selenium, proxy

Alright, I'm back again... with another Selenium 3.x/geckodriver question.

I currently have a setup where I'm routing all network traffic from my selenium tests through browsermob-proxy, so my tests require that I give them the proxy information route all of that data through so that later I can query it.

I'm currently having an issue that no matter how I try and set up the proxy, I get different exceptions from my tests.

Attempt 1: Setting proxy through socks

```
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9091);
```

This attempt results in the following stack trace:

```
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
InvalidArgumentError: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be an integer
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a299:9bff:fe05:a43b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:        0x10d573754 - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h8e94df436d083743
   1:        0x10d573b2f - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he142908a5a8f9eda
   2:        0x10d203cbf - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h160d25bec9197da5
   3:        0x10d211442 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteSession::response::h970369545ccb2ae5
   4:        0x10d2205aa - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteConnection::send_command::h4b272021662c39d8
   5:        0x10d20fd48 - _$LT$geckodriver..marionette..MarionetteHandler$u20$as$u20$webdriver..server..WebDriverHandler$LT$geckodriver..marionette..GeckoExtensionRoute$GT$$GT$::handle_command::h2c7905f1d7536e5d
   6:        0x10d198d43 - _$LT$webdriver..server..Dispatcher$LT$T$C$$u20$U$GT$$GT$::run::hd1e66b7b65330ddf
   7:        0x10d204b1a - webdriver::server::start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h690494072298ecdc
   8:        0x10d0fcbaa - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h9a6ad1a465c9c77e
   9:        0x10d10dd83 - std::thread::Builder::spawn::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hb084b9313dc657eb
  10:        0x10d0bbb7a - _$LT$std..panic..AssertUnwindSafe$LT$F$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$$LP$$RP$$GT$$GT$::call_once::h9e0d4487cab44eb7
  11:        0x10d10e8b9 - std::panicking::try::do_call::hd4a4ecf8d08f7d4d
  12:        0x10d89567c - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
  13:        0x10d10e6ec - std::panicking::try::hdaf1b8a3b363a07e
  14:        0x10d10b5e5 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h9643785660d717d4
  15:        0x10d10da3e - std::thread::Builder::spawn::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hc86bbe5d0f3f926a
  16:        0x10d17b663 - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h9cb8abeb542e88ca
  17:        0x10d8918eb - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h2d2a40d6b00ba029
  18:     0x7fff99df499c - _pthread_body
  19:     0x7fff99df4919 - _pthread_start
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a299:9bff:fe05:a43b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Attempt 2: Setting via JSON

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("proxyType", "MANUAL");
json.addProperty("httpProxy", "127.0.0.1");
json.addProperty("httpProxyPort", 9091);
json.addProperty("sslProxy", "127.0.0.1");
json.addProperty("sslProxyPort", 9091);

capabilities.setCapability("proxy", json);
```

Which results in the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException:
httpProxyPort was not a valid proxy configuration capability
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a299:9bff:fe05:a43b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:        0x107004754 - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h8e94df436d083743
   1:        0x107004b2f - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he142908a5a8f9eda
   2:        0x106d19c3f - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h3c5206efc2aea993
   3:        0x106d07fe9 - webdriver::capabilities::SpecNewSessionParameters::validate_proxy::h0d2c552864af830d
   4:        0x106c93b2b - webdriver::capabilities::SpecNewSessionParameters::validate::ha71de94fac9331d9
   5:        0x106b509e6 - _$LT$webdriver..capabilities..SpecNewSessionParameters$u20$as$u20$webdriver..capabilities..CapabilitiesMatching$GT$::match_browser::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h1c32cd867ef807c3
   6:        0x106bbf37b - _$LT$core..result..Result$LT$T$C$$u20$E$GT$$GT$::and_then::hf76bfa0e307d12b7
   7:        0x106b4fd44 - _$LT$webdriver..capabilities..SpecNewSessionParameters$u20$as$u20$webdriver..capabilities..CapabilitiesMatching$GT$::match_browser::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::ha440f562183a4100
   8:        0x106beb870 - core::ops::function::impls::_$LT$impl$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$A$GT$$u20$for$u20$$RF$$u27$a$u20$mut$u20$F$GT$::call_once::h97d995e0820d8c8b
   9:        0x106b80fd5 - _$LT$core..option..Option$LT$T$GT$$GT$::map::hec1c45e28df3f669
  10:        0x106c7ed4c - _$LT$core..iter..Map$LT$I$C$$u20$F$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..iter..iterator..Iterator$GT$::next::h3e80bbc98e18278b
  11:        0x106b6b156 - _$LT$$LT$core..result..Result$LT$V$C$$u20$E$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..iter..traits..FromIterator$LT$core..result..Result$LT$A$C$$u20$E$GT$$GT$$GT$..from_iter..Adapter$LT$Iter$C$$u20$E$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..iter..iterator..Iterator$GT$::next::hef0037ea92f136e0
  12:        0x106c69db6 - _$LT$$RF$$u27$a$u20$mut$u20$I$u20$as$u20$core..iter..iterator..Iterator$GT$::next::h13a60fd6da24f240
  13:        0x106c84069 - _$LT$alloc..vec..Vec$LT$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$alloc..vec..SpecExtend$LT$T$C$$u20$I$GT$$GT$::from_iter::h3c5cd3bebd0b7a94
  14:        0x106c85ebb - _$LT$alloc..vec..Vec$LT$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..iter..traits..FromIterator$LT$T$GT$$GT$::from_iter::h0a9ec0a7d8599d2f
  15:        0x106b5517b - _$LT$core..result..Result$LT$V$C$$u20$E$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..iter..traits..FromIterator$LT$core..result..Result$LT$A$C$$u20$E$GT$$GT$$GT$::from_iter::h3912ad22da5fa8a1
  16:        0x106c05d06 - core::iter::iterator::Iterator::collect::h37a3ccf2360609f5
  17:        0x106b4f700 - _$LT$webdriver..capabilities..SpecNewSessionParameters$u20$as$u20$webdriver..capabilities..CapabilitiesMatching$GT$::match_browser::h68cf564270268ccf
  18:        0x106b4e5f5 - _$LT$webdriver..command..NewSessionParameters$u20$as$u20$webdriver..capabilities..CapabilitiesMatching$GT$::match_browser::hbc7b5070d6ac176e
  19:        0x106c9dcb7 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::h48a7098743d092a0
  20:        0x106ca0a71 - _$LT$geckodriver..marionette..MarionetteHandler$u20$as$u20$webdriver..server..WebDriverHandler$LT$geckodriver..marionette..GeckoExtensionRoute$GT$$GT$::handle_command::h2c7905f1d7536e5d
  21:        0x106c29d43 - _$LT$webdriver..server..Dispatcher$LT$T$C$$u20$U$GT$$GT$::run::hd1e66b7b65330ddf
  22:        0x106c95b1a - webdriver::server::start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h690494072298ecdc
  23:        0x106b8dbaa - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h9a6ad1a465c9c77e
  24:        0x106b9ed83 - std::thread::Builder::spawn::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hb084b9313dc657eb
  25:        0x106b4cb7a - _$LT$std..panic..AssertUnwindSafe$LT$F$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$$LP$$RP$$GT$$GT$::call_once::h9e0d4487cab44eb7
  26:        0x106b9f8b9 - std::panicking::try::do_call::hd4a4ecf8d08f7d4d
  27:        0x10732667c - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
  28:        0x106b9f6ec - std::panicking::try::hdaf1b8a3b363a07e
  29:        0x106b9c5e5 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h9643785660d717d4
  30:        0x106b9ea3e - std::thread::Builder::spawn::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hc86bbe5d0f3f926a
  31:        0x106c0c663 - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h9cb8abeb542e88ca
  32:        0x1073228eb - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h2d2a40d6b00ba029
  33:     0x7fff99df499c - _pthread_body
  34:     0x7fff99df4919 - _pthread_start
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a299:9bff:fe05:a43b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Attempt 3:  Set through setPreference, without socks

```
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 9091);
```

Which results in the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
InvalidArgumentError: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be an integer
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a299:9bff:fe05:a43b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:        0x10f5b6754 - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h8e94df436d083743
   1:        0x10f5b6b2f - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he142908a5a8f9eda
   2:        0x10f246cbf - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h160d25bec9197da5
   3:        0x10f254442 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteSession::response::h970369545ccb2ae5
   4:        0x10f2635aa - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteConnection::send_command::h4b272021662c39d8
   5:        0x10f252d48 - _$LT$geckodriver..marionette..MarionetteHandler$u20$as$u20$webdriver..server..WebDriverHandler$LT$geckodriver..marionette..GeckoExtensionRoute$GT$$GT$::handle_command::h2c7905f1d7536e5d
   6:        0x10f1dbd43 - _$LT$webdriver..server..Dispatcher$LT$T$C$$u20$U$GT$$GT$::run::hd1e66b7b65330ddf
   7:        0x10f247b1a - webdriver::server::start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h690494072298ecdc
   8:        0x10f13fbaa - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h9a6ad1a465c9c77e
   9:        0x10f150d83 - std::thread::Builder::spawn::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hb084b9313dc657eb
  10:        0x10f0feb7a - _$LT$std..panic..AssertUnwindSafe$LT$F$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$$LP$$RP$$GT$$GT$::call_once::h9e0d4487cab44eb7
  11:        0x10f1518b9 - std::panicking::try::do_call::hd4a4ecf8d08f7d4d
  12:        0x10f8d867c - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
  13:        0x10f1516ec - std::panicking::try::hdaf1b8a3b363a07e
  14:        0x10f14e5e5 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h9643785660d717d4
  15:        0x10f150a3e - std::thread::Builder::spawn::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hc86bbe5d0f3f926a
  16:        0x10f1be663 - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h9cb8abeb542e88ca
  17:        0x10f8d48eb - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h2d2a40d6b00ba029
  18:     0x7fff99df499c - _pthread_body
  19:     0x7fff99df4919 - _pthread_start
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:a299:9bff:fe05:a43b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

What is the appropriate way to set a proxy with geckodriver and selenium??

I'm using Selenium 3.5.3 and geckodriver 0.19

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the entire method that I'm using to do these modifications to firefox and other browsers.....  I'm using Selion, so that may factor in as well.

```
package com.iacapps.ste.ta.helpers;

import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import com.paypal.selion.platform.grid.Grid;
import com.paypal.selion.platform.grid.browsercapabilities.DefaultCapabilitiesBuilder;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Collections;

public class CustomCapabilities extends DefaultCapabilitiesBuilder
{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultCapabilitiesBuilder.class);

  private static final String SAUCE_TUNNEL_PROPERTY = "sauceTunnel";
  private static final String SAUCE_ENABLED_PROPERTY = "enableSauceConnect";
  private static final String TUNNEL_CAPABILITY = "tunnelIdentifier";
  private static final String ACCEPT_ALL_SSL_CAPABILITY = "acceptSslCerts";
  private static final String CHROME_SWITCHES = "chrome.switches";
  private static final String CHROME_IGNORE_SSL = "--ignore-certificate-errors";
  private static final String FIREFOX_ACCEPT_BAD_CERTS_CAPABILITY = "acceptInsecureCerts";

  @Override
  public DesiredCapabilities getCapabilities(DesiredCapabilities capabilities)
  {
    String sauceEnabledValue = System.getProperty(SAUCE_ENABLED_PROPERTY);
    String tunnelIdValue = System.getProperty(SAUCE_TUNNEL_PROPERTY);
    //This will just prevent the warning being printed when sauceconnect isn't enabled.
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(sauceEnabledValue) && Boolean.valueOf(sauceEnabledValue))
    {
      if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(tunnelIdValue))
      {
        logger.warn("{} not set", SAUCE_TUNNEL_PROPERTY);
      }
      else
      {
        // TODO:  Maybe move this to non-firefox browsers??
        //capabilities.setCapability(TUNNEL_CAPABILITY, tunnelIdValue);
      }
    }


    // Seems like with the latest version of selenium (3.x) we need to be kinda specific about
    // making sure that we're going to pass the right configuration crap to the particular drivers.
    // So for now, I'm just going to make some broad strokes and make things so that we know
    // if we're on firefox or "not firefox".  This might need to be changed/updated as we see that
    // other browsers aren't going to play nice with this, but well.  I hope it fixes it for now :)

    if (!Grid.getWebTestSession().getBrowser().contains("firefox"))
    {

      //There's a reason for this charlie foxtrot.  I don't always get to know what browser driver I'm
      //talking to.
      //Per selenium docs: "Whether the session should accept all SSL certs by default."
      //The DOWNSIDE: this seems to work with newer browser drivers, but it may not work with old ones.
      capabilities.setCapability(ACCEPT_ALL_SSL_CAPABILITY, true);
      //This *supposedly* works with some versions of IE.
      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
      //This *supposedly* works with some chrome versions.

      capabilities.setCapability(CHROME_SWITCHES, Collections.singletonList(CHROME_IGNORE_SSL));
    }


    if (Grid.getWebTestSession().getBrowser().contains("firefox"))
    {

          //Oh my god please work you STUPID FIREFOX
          //http://stackoverflow.com/a/40788935
          //https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196
          //Should work with firefox > v51
          capabilities.setCapability(FIREFOX_ACCEPT_BAD_CERTS_CAPABILITY,true);
          //When in doubt SET EVERYTHING!


          FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

          // Okay, let's try this socks stuff
          // Okay, socks doesn't work either.  Same object undefined nonsense.
          /*profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
          profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks", "localhost");
          profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9091);*/


          // When attempting to set via profile, I get this
          // InvalidArgumentError: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be an integer
          profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
          profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "127.0.0.1");
          profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 9091);


          // JSON Type 1.
          // So with the JSON object I get a httpProxyPort not a valid option....
          /*JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
          json.addProperty("proxyType", "MANUAL");
          json.addProperty("httpProxy", "127.0.0.1");
          json.addProperty("httpProxyPort", 9091);
          json.addProperty("sslProxy", "127.0.0.1");
          json.addProperty("sslProxyPort", 9091);

          capabilities.setCapability("proxy", json);*/

          // JSON type 2.
          // So with the JSON object I get a httpProxyPort not a valid option....
          /*JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
          json.addProperty("proxyType", "manual");
          json.addProperty("httpProxy", "localhost");
          json.addProperty("httpProxyPort", 9091);
          //json.addProperty("ftpProxy", "localhost");
          //json.addProperty("ftpProxyPort", 9091);
          json.addProperty("sslProxy", "localhost");
          json.addProperty("sslProxyPort", 9091);
          capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, json);*/

          profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
          profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
          profile.setPreference("broswer.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
          capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,profile);
          // Marionette is for older versions of firefox with geckodriver.  So if you want to do
          // That you need to have it enabled.

          // Currently I'm getting a few different results depending on what I have this set to.
          // TRUE or not set:
            // Session not created: InvalidArgumentError: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be an integer
            // Opens browser.  Closes it too.  Fails right away.
          // FALSE:
            // java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            // Opens the browser and then doesn't do anything with it.  Times out.
          //capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE,true);
    }
    return capabilities;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");` try using `profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "127.0.0.1");` and see if that helps

Comment: Tarun, thank you for the attempt... no change.  Still the same stack trace.

Comment: Can you post the complete code your tried?

Comment: The only other code in this that affects firefox is:

          `profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
          profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
          profile.setPreference("broswer.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
          capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,profile);`

Comment: Feels like there is mistake in initialized object, can you show your code with object initialization ?

Comment: @Teresa, i have launched firefox with profile and it works, so there is something that you are doing wrong

Comment: So I'm using selion, which may be part of the picture as well.  I'm not entirely certain.  I edited the above question to include the entire text of the method that I'm using for modification of the capabilities and supplying the proxy information.  Including the commented out code that I showed above for things that I've tried.

Answer (score 4):

After struggling for days reading forums etc. found out that Firefox version 57 helps! It is fixed in that version.
Using selenium-java 3.6.0, selenium firefox driver 3.6.0, with **firefox 57** (currently beta), mac os x 10.12.6, geckodriver 0.19.0 solves this problem!

```
//call with String "host:port"
private FirefoxDriver createDriverWithProxy( String proxyIpPort) {

    org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyIpPort)
            .setFtpProxy(proxyIpPort)
            .setSslProxy(proxyIpPort);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(cap);
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: How do I add noProxy to the capabilities?

Comment: @Ismoh `proxy.setNoProxy(java.lang.String noProxy)` look in documentation here https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

- firefox：59.0.1
- geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64
- selenium-java-3.9.1.jar
- java8

This works well.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

options.addPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
options.addPreference("network.proxy.socks", "23.23.23.1");
options.addPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
options.addPreference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", true);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```