# Insecure connection error in Firefox using Selenium webdriver using java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

FF: 52.6 ESR version
Selenium : 3.5.2
Gecko driver : v0.15

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/geckodrivers/geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");       
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I am using this code and still getting insecure connection error. If I use capabilities, the url itself is not opening in FF browser. Issue not replicating in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Firefox's untrusted connection warning using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879566/how-to-disable-firefoxs-untrusted-connection-warning-using-selenium)