# Preventing "Warning Potential Security Risk Ahead" in selenium python Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-marionette

So when using selenium python with firefox I need to prevent this:
[image]

This is what I have already tried

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
profile.accept_insecure_certs = True
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
firefox = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=utils.str_master_dir('geckodriver.exe'), options=profile)
...
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

You can also create a custom Firefox profile as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41508391/3485434)

Comment: The `webdriver.Firefox` constructor does not have a `desired_capabilities` argument (anymore). It's frustrating to see how often these APIs seem to chage. I've found 5 different "fixes" for this problem but none seems to work as of today.