# Accept Untrusted Certificates on anonymous profile in firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I have a small issue.I am opening a firefox browser in a specific profile with selenium,and an flash app
appear.In this app I need to click something,so I use sikuli.The problem is when clicking a button with sikuli,my app opens a browser in an anonymous profile so the "Untrusted SSL certificates" appears.

Is there any way to setAcceptUntrustedCertificates for anonymous profiles for firefox ?

I want to mention that I already have setAcceptUntrustedCertificates in my java code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a profile for the driver and use

```
 profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates (true);
```

Also this has been answered before for example see

[Handling UntrustedSSLcertificates using WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933871/handling-untrustedsslcertificates-using-webdriver)

Comment: It doesn't work.After I click the flash app it opens a browser where the SSL certificates appear.