# Accepting untrusted SSL certificate for Internet explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing selenium automation test scripts for Accepting untrusted SSL certificate.It works fine for Firefox and Chrome browsers.
For firefox , This link helped me [Handling UntrustedSSLcertificates using WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933871/handling-untrustedsslcertificates-using-webdriver)

Accepting untrusted SSL certificate for Internet explorer 9 and 10 is not working for me .

Tried to find best results on net but could not find it.
Can someone provide me the links or some code that could help me  Accepting untrusted SSL certificate for Internet explorer 9 and Internet explorer 10.