# How to handle "Your connection is not secure" error in firefox using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am using webdriver V 3.0.1 and firefox V 46. I am facing an error as "Your connection is not secure".

[image]

Please help me to overcome from this issue. Below you can find my code

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Software\\Webdriver\\gecko new\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 0);
    profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true); 
    profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    driver.get("http://qa.applications.marykayintouch.com/Login/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: in browser your URL is displaying with `https` and in your code `http`  . Why it is so ?

Comment: By default it is changed to https. application is launching successfully and goes back to not secure page.

Comment: I tried all the solutions which are suggested on this page but bad luck. I am using Webdriver 3.0.1 and firefox browser V 50.1.0.

I can able to navigate to common sites like google, facebook, Gmail. But the below-mentioned URL is not navigating "https://qa.applications.marykayintouch.com/Login/Login.aspx". Manually it is working fine. Kindly help me

Comment: @Ashok Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

To me, the most simple and efficient solution was to do this

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions()
{
    AcceptInsecureCertificates = true
};

using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options))
{
    // Your code
}
```

I tried using Sanjay Bhimani's example but it didn't work so looked into the available constructors and ended up with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems SSLCertificates error
Just try with editing capabilities

```
ProfilesIni profiles = new ProfilesIni();
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile","custom firefox profile name");
String browser_profile = System.getProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile");
FirefoxProfile profile = profiles.getProfile(browser_profile); 
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates (true); 
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

or

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

or

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
ProfilesIni profiles = new ProfilesIni();
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile","custom firefox profile name");
String browser_profile = System.getProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile");
FirefoxProfile profile = profiles.getProfile(browser_profile); 
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true); 
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I tried all the solutions which are suggested on this page but bad luck. I am using Webdriver 3.0.1 and firefox browser V 50.1.0.

I can able to navigate to common sites like google, facebook, Gmail. But the below-mentioned URL is not navigating "https://qa.applications.marykayintouch.com/Login/Login.aspx". Manually it is working fine. Kindly help me

Comment: I tried all the solutions which are suggested on this page but bad luck. I am using Webdriver 3.0.1 and firefox browser V 50.1.0.

I can able to navigate to common sites like google, facebook, Gmail. But the below-mentioned URL is not navigating "https://qa.applications.marykayintouch.com/Login/Login.aspx". Manually it is working fine. Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

For handling SSL certificate error in Firefox, we need to use desired capabilities of Selenium Webdriver and follow the following steps:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile","your custom firefox profile name");
String browserProfile = stem.getProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile");
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile(browserProfile); 
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates (true); 
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

You can refer the following for reference:
[Handling UntrustedSSLcertificates using WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933871/handling-untrustedsslcertificates-using-webdriver)

Comment: I tried all the solutions which are suggested on this page but bad luck. I am using Webdriver 3.0.1 and firefox browser V 50.1.0.

I can able to navigate to common sites like google, facebook, Gmail. But the below-mentioned URL is not navigating "https://qa.applications.marykayintouch.com/Login/Login.aspx". Manually it is working fine. Kindly help me