# Selenium firefox - WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:certerror

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

**Meta :-**

- Firefox v51.0.1 (32-bit)
- Windows 10
- Selenium 3.0.1
- Geckodriver Win32 v0.13.0
- Java v1.8.0_71

**Steps to reproduce :-**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("untrusted/self-signed URL")
```

**Stacktrace :-**

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:certerror?e=nssBadCert&u=xxxxxxxx&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=xxxxxx%20uses%20an%20invalid%20security%20certificate.%0A%0AThe%20certificate%20is%20not%20trusted%20because%20it%20is%20self-signed.%0AThe%20certificate%20is%20not%20valid%20for%20the%20name%20xxxxxx%0A%0AError%20code%3A%20%3Ca%20id%3D%22errorCode%22%20title%3D%22SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER%22%3ESEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER%3C/a%3E%0A
>   Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'Saurabh-PC', ip: '192.168.3.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

**Screenshot :-**

[image]

I have also tried using `FirefoxProfile` as :-

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);

dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
driver.get("untrusted/self-signed URL");
```

But issue is the same as above.

**Reference Link which have tried :-**

- [How to disable Firefox's untrusted connection warning using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879566/how-to-disable-firefoxs-untrusted-connection-warning-using-selenium)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/webdriver/frWtNrEwNPk
- [Handling UntrustedSSLcertificates using WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933871/handling-untrustedsslcertificates-using-webdriver)

---

According to [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1329965) Support for untrusted/self-signed certificates has been added via [bug 1103196](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196) and will be available starting with `Firefox 52`.

But I could not find any solution for `Firefox v51.0.1 (32-bit)`.

Is there any way to solve this issue using `Firefox v51.0.1 (32-bit)`?

Comment: Manually visit the site once and add the certificate to Firefox's exception list?

Comment: @JimGarrison already done, and it's open fine manually after doing this but when open it using selenium issue is the same..:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1329965) mentioned Support for untrusted/self-signed certificates will be available starting with `Firefox 52`, we need to wait until `Firefox 52` is not released.

---

**Solution :-**
For now, as alternate solution we need to use existing `Firefox profile` where the certificate for **untrusted/self-signed** URL is already added into `Firefox's exception list`.

> How to create custom Firefox profile for selenium?

- [Need to follow this link to create manually custom Firefox profile](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/)
- Add manually certificate for untrusted/self-signed URL into Firefox's exception list

[image]

- Launch Firefox using existing profile as :-

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver")

  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
  FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("created Profile Name");

  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
  driver.get("untrusted/self-signed URL");
  ```