# Peer’s certificate has an invalid signature. Error code: SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE error with Selenium GeckoDriver and Firefox through Java

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Connecting to one website. After typing login and password values, when clicked on Sign IN button, seeing the below error on the UI.

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to wgateway-fit.nj.adp.com. Peer’s certificate has an invalid signature. Error code: SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE
```

We are using Selenium c#. Firefox Browser 66

```
FirefoxOptions option = new FirefoxOptions();
//option.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";   
option.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Users\buskarna\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
option.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
option.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/html;charset=iso-8859-1,application/dat,application/pdf,text/plain,text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/octet-stream,application/download,text/x-csv");
option.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "text/html;charset=iso-8859-1,application/dat,application/pdf,text/plain,text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/octet-stream,application/download,text/x-csv");
option.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
option.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Temp\\");
option.SetPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf,application/vnd.fdf");
option.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
option.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
option.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
option.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
option.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
option.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
```

Comment: Is something else on that machine running on the same port that Selenium is trying to connect to? (And is that thing requiring a secure connection with an invalid SSL certificate?)

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359835/selenium-firefox-webdriverexception-reached-error-page-aboutcerterror

Comment: @NarasimhaRao Do you use any anti virus e.g. Avast?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that random pages are being blocked by Firefox - `SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE` is displayed. Other browsers were fine.

**SOLUTION**

Renaming two files has 'reset' firefox files and resolved the above issue.

- cert8.db to cert8.db.old
- cert9.db to cert9.db.old

Windows 10 directory:
`C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\yuic7va7.default`

where `YOURUSERNAME` is the name of your Windows profile
and

`yuic7va7.default` is a default, and probably random, name of the Firefox profile.

The above worked on 69.0.1 (64-bit) Firefox, Windows 10 and Windows 7 computers.